# How do I combine two features / classifiers into a single united and better classifier?

Tags: python, matrix, scikit-learn, classification, feature-selection

I am creating an emotion recognition program and managed to produce two different algorithms/features to feed into sklearn's SVM. I got Dense Optical Flow data, compacted it into a matrix and feed it into the SVM function while I did the same with tracking data from facial landmarks.

Right now, I have two different programs that each produces different accuracy, but does the same thing: recognizing emotion based on facial movement.

My goal right now is to combine both dense optical flow and facial landmark features / classifiers together and unite them to get one better classifier that would use both of those to achieve higher accuracy in classification.

Basically, I am trying to recreate a classifier from this:
http://cgit.nutn.edu.tw:8080/cgit/PaperDL/LZJ_120826151743.PDF

```
Confusion Matrix for Dense Optical Flow:   
[[27 22  0  0]  
 [ 0 57  1  0]  
 [ 0 12 60  0]  
 [ 0  9  3 68]]  
Accuracy: 80-90% range

Confusion Matrix for Facial Landmarks:  
[[27 10  5  2]  
 [ 7 44  5  3]  
 [ 6 14 33  1]  
 [ 1 13  1 60]]  
Accuracy: 60-72% range
```

Matrix structure of matrix containing Dense Optical Flow data:

```
>>> main.shape
(646, 403680)
>>> main
array([[ -1.18353125e-03,  -2.41295085e-04,  -1.88367767e-03, ...,
         -5.19892928e-05,   8.53588153e-06,  -3.90818786e-05],
       [  6.32877424e-02,  -7.24349543e-02,   8.19472596e-02, ...,
         -4.71765925e-05,   5.41217596e-05,  -3.12083102e-05],
       [ -1.66368652e-02,   2.50510368e-02,  -6.03965335e-02, ...,
         -9.85100851e-05,  -7.69595645e-05,  -7.09727174e-05],
       ..., 
       [ -3.44874617e-03,   5.31123485e-03,  -8.47499538e-03, ...,
         -2.77953018e-06,  -2.96417579e-06,  -1.51305017e-06],
       [  3.24894954e-03,   5.05338283e-03,   3.91049543e-03, ...,
         -3.23493354e-04,   1.30995919e-04,  -3.06804082e-04],
       [  7.82454386e-03,   1.69946514e-02,   8.11014231e-03, ...,
         -1.02751539e-03,   7.68289610e-05,  -7.82517891e-04]], dtype=float32)
```

Matrix structure of matrix containing face landmark tracking information:

```
>>> main.shape
(646, 17, 68, 2)
>>> main
array([[[[  0.        ,   0.        ],
         [  0.        ,   0.        ],
         [  0.        ,   0.        ],
         ..., 
         [  0.        ,   0.        ],
         [  0.        ,   0.        ],
         [  0.        ,   0.        ]],

        [[ -2.23606798,  -1.10714872],
         [ -2.23606798,  -1.10714872],
         [  3.        ,   1.        ],
         ..., 
         [  1.41421356,   0.78539816],
         [  1.41421356,   0.78539816],
         [  1.        ,   0.        ]],

        [[  2.82842712,  -0.78539816],
         [  2.23606798,  -1.10714872],
         [  2.23606798,  -1.10714872],
         ..., 
         [ -1.        ,  -0.        ],
         [ -1.        ,  -0.        ],
         [ -1.        ,  -0.        ]],

        ..., 
        [[  2.        ,   1.        ],
         [ -2.23606798,   1.10714872],
         [ -3.16227766,   1.24904577],
         ..., 
         [ -1.        ,  -0.        ],
         [ -1.41421356,   0.78539816],
         [ -1.        ,  -0.        ]],

        [[ -1.41421356,  -0.78539816],
         [  1.        ,   1.        ],
         [ -1.41421356,  -0.78539816],
         ..., 
         [  0.        ,   0.        ],
         [  0.        ,   0.        ],
         [  0.        ,   0.        ]],

        [[  3.        ,   1.        ],
         [  4.        ,   1.        ],
         [  4.        ,   1.        ],
         ..., 
         [  1.41421356,  -0.78539816],
         [  1.        ,   0.        ],
         [  1.        ,   0.        ]]],


       [[[  0.        ,   0.        ],
         [  0.        ,   0.        ],
         [  0.        ,   0.        ],
         ..., 
         [  0.        ,   0.        ],
         [  0.        ,   0.        ],
         [  0.        ,   0.        ]],

        [[  1.        ,   1.        ],
         [ -1.41421356,  -0.78539816],
         [ -1.        ,  -0.        ],
         ..., 
         [  2.        ,   0.        ],
         [  1.        ,   0.        ],
         [ -1.        ,  -0.        ]],

        [[  0.        ,   0.        ],
         [  1.        ,   1.        ],
         [  0.        ,   0.        ],
         ..., 
         [ -4.        ,  -0.        ],
         [ -3.        ,  -0.        ],
         [ -2.        ,  -0.        ]],

        ..., 
        [[ -2.23606798,  -1.10714872],
         [ -2.23606798,  -1.10714872],
         [  2.        ,   1.        ],
         ..., 
         [  0.        ,   0.        ],
         [  1.41421356,   0.78539816],
         [  1.41421356,   0.78539816]],

        [[  0.        ,   0.        ],
         [  0.        ,   0.        ],
         [ -1.        ,  -0.        ],
         ..., 
         [  1.        ,   1.        ],
         [  0.        ,   0.        ],
         [ -1.41421356,   0.78539816]],

        [[  1.        ,   1.        ],
         [  1.        ,   1.        ],
         [  1.        ,   1.        ],
         ..., 
         [  1.        ,   1.        ],
         [  0.        ,   0.        ],
         [  1.        ,   0.        ]]],


       [[[  0.        ,   0.        ],
         [  0.        ,   0.        ],
         [  0.        ,   0.        ],
         ..., 
         [  0.        ,   0.        ],
         [  0.        ,   0.        ],
         [  0.        ,   0.        ]],

        [[  3.16227766,   1.24904577],
         [  2.23606798,   1.10714872],
         [  2.23606798,   1.10714872],
         ..., 
         [ -1.41421356,  -0.78539816],
         [ -1.        ,  -0.        ],
         [ -1.41421356,   0.78539816]],

        [[ -1.41421356,   0.78539816],
         [  0.        ,   0.        ],
         [  1.41421356,   0.78539816],
         ..., 
         [ -1.41421356,   0.78539816],
         [ -1.        ,  -0.        ],
         [  0.        ,   0.        ]],

        ..., 
        [[  1.        ,   1.        ],
         [  1.        ,   1.        ],
         [  0.        ,   0.        ],
         ..., 
         [  1.        ,   1.        ],
         [  1.        ,   1.        ],
         [ -1.41421356,   0.78539816]],

        [[  1.        ,   1.        ],
         [  2.        ,   1.        ],
         [  2.23606798,   1.10714872],
         ..., 
         [  1.        ,   1.        ],
         [  1.        ,   1.        ],
         [ -1.41421356,  -0.78539816]],

        [[  1.        ,   1.        ],
         [  1.        ,   1.        ],
         [  1.        ,   1.        ],
         ..., 
         [ -2.        ,  -0.        ],
         [ -2.        ,  -0.        ],
         [ -1.        ,  -0.        ]]],


       ..., 
       [[[  0.        ,   0.        ],
         [  0.        ,   0.        ],
         [  0.        ,   0.        ],
         ..., 
         [  0.        ,   0.        ],
         [  0.        ,   0.        ],
         [  0.        ,   0.        ]],

        [[  1.41421356,   0.78539816],
         [  1.41421356,   0.78539816],
         [  1.41421356,   0.78539816],
         ..., 
         [  1.        ,   1.        ],
         [  0.        ,   0.        ],
         [  1.        ,   1.        ]],

        [[  5.        ,   1.        ],
         [ -4.12310563,   1.32581766],
         [ -4.12310563,   1.32581766],
         ..., 
         [  1.        ,   1.        ],
         [  0.        ,   0.        ],
         [  1.        ,   1.        ]],

        ..., 
        [[  3.16227766,   1.24904577],
         [  2.        ,   1.        ],
         [  2.        ,   1.        ],
         ..., 
         [  0.        ,   0.        ],
         [  0.        ,   0.        ],
         [  0.        ,   0.        ]],

        [[ -3.16227766,   1.24904577],
         [  2.        ,   1.        ],
         [ -2.23606798,   1.10714872],
         ..., 
         [  0.        ,   0.        ],
         [  1.        ,   0.        ],
         [  1.        ,   0.        ]],

        [[  1.        ,   1.        ],
         [  1.        ,   1.        ],
         [  1.41421356,   0.78539816],
         ..., 
         [  0.        ,   0.        ],
         [  0.        ,   0.        ],
         [  0.        ,   0.        ]]],


       [[[  0.        ,   0.        ],
         [  0.        ,   0.        ],
         [  0.        ,   0.        ],
         ..., 
         [  0.        ,   0.        ],
         [  0.        ,   0.        ],
         [  0.        ,   0.        ]],

        [[ -2.23606798,   0.46364761],
         [ -1.41421356,   0.78539816],
         [ -2.23606798,   0.46364761],
         ..., 
         [  1.        ,   0.        ],
         [  1.        ,   0.        ],
         [  1.        ,   1.        ]],

        [[ -2.23606798,  -0.46364761],
         [ -1.41421356,  -0.78539816],
         [  2.        ,   1.        ],
         ..., 
         [  0.        ,   0.        ],
         [  1.        ,   0.        ],
         [  1.        ,   0.        ]],

        ..., 
        [[  1.        ,   0.        ],
         [  1.        ,   1.        ],
         [ -2.23606798,  -1.10714872],
         ..., 
         [ 19.02629759,   1.51821327],
         [ 19.        ,   1.        ],
         [-19.10497317,  -1.46591939]],

        [[  3.60555128,   0.98279372],
         [  3.60555128,   0.5880026 ],
         [  5.        ,   0.64350111],
         ..., 
         [  7.28010989,  -1.29249667],
         [  7.61577311,  -1.16590454],
         [  8.06225775,  -1.05165021]],

        [[ -7.28010989,   1.29249667],
         [ -5.        ,   0.92729522],
         [ -5.83095189,   0.5404195 ],
         ..., 
         [ 20.09975124,   1.47112767],
         [ 21.02379604,   1.52321322],
         [-20.22374842,  -1.42190638]]],


       [[[  0.        ,   0.        ],
         [  0.        ,   0.        ],
         [  0.        ,   0.        ],
         ..., 
         [  0.        ,   0.        ],
         [  0.        ,   0.        ],
         [  0.        ,   0.        ]],

        [[ -1.41421356,   0.78539816],
         [ -2.23606798,   1.10714872],
         [  2.        ,   1.        ],
         ..., 
         [  1.        ,   1.        ],
         [  1.        ,   0.        ],
         [  2.23606798,  -0.46364761]],

        [[  1.        ,   0.        ],
         [  1.41421356,   0.78539816],
         [  1.        ,   1.        ],
         ..., 
         [  0.        ,   0.        ],
         [  1.        ,   1.        ],
         [  0.        ,   0.        ]],

        ..., 
        [[ -1.41421356,  -0.78539816],
         [  0.        ,   0.        ],
         [  1.        ,   1.        ],
         ..., 
         [  1.        ,   0.        ],
         [  1.        ,   0.        ],
         [  1.        ,   0.        ]],

        [[  1.        ,   1.        ],
         [ -1.        ,  -0.        ],
         [  1.        ,   1.        ],
         ..., 
         [ -1.        ,  -0.        ],
         [  0.        ,   0.        ],
         [ -1.        ,  -0.        ]],

        [[  0.        ,   0.        ],
         [  1.41421356,  -0.78539816],
         [ -1.        ,  -0.        ],
         ..., 
         [  1.        ,   0.        ],
         [  0.        ,   0.        ],
         [  1.        ,   0.        ]]]])
```

My code for Dense Optical Flow classifier:

```
features_train, features_test, labels_train, labels_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(main, target, test_size = 0.4)

# Determine amount of time to train
t0 = time()
model = SVC(probability=True)
#model = SVC(kernel='poly')
#model = GaussianNB()

model.fit(features_train, labels_train)

print 'training time: ', round(time()-t0, 3), 's'

# Determine amount of time to predict
t1 = time()
pred = model.predict(features_test)
```

My code for Face Landmark Tracking classifier:

```
features_train, features_test, labels_train, labels_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(main.reshape(len(main), -1), target, test_size = 0.4)

# Determine amount of time to train
t0 = time()
#model = SVC()
model = SVC(kernel='linear')

#model = GaussianNB()

model.fit(features_train, labels_train)


# Determine amount of time to predict
t1 = time()
pred = model.predict(features_test)
```

In sklearn (or machine learning in general), how do I combine these two features together in order to create an united and better classifier that takes these two information into account when training and predicting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [VotingClassifier](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/ensemble.html#votingclassifier). It allows you to combine multiple classifiers and select the final prediction based on the individual predictions from each classifier.

The above is assuming that you're OK with using the dev (0.17) version of sklearn. If not you can copy the VotingClassifier source to your code: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/ensemble/voting_classifier.py. The code is pretty simple.

Answer (score 0):

You can build separate classifiers as suggested by Daniel. However, you might consider concatenating your two data sets:

```
main_dense_optical
main_face_landmark = main_face_landmark.reshape( len(main_face_landmark), -1 )
main = np.concatenate( [main_dense_optical, main_face_landmark], axis=1 )
# Code for train/test, training, evaluating here
```

Comment: I considered about that and usually would do something like that, but I fear that since some of the features are different from each other,